# Как спрятать окно (в том числе в панели задач)?

Tags: delphi

Мне нужно, чтобы окно, в том числе и вот это

[image]

скрывалось при запуске программы. Как это сделать?

Comment: Эх, давно я программировал на Delphi... Может быть, `Window.hide()`?

Comment: Хоть и не Window.hide() а Form1.Hide; но всё равно большое спасибо!!!

Comment: @Андрющенко Андрей, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Никогда не думал, что скажу такое кому-нибудь, но, поразмыслив над вопросами задаваемыми ТС каждый день, могу порекомендовать печальную книгу Фленова "Delphi глазами хакера". Там есть все, что вас интересует в данный момент.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к @Nofate.

Comment: Книжку делфи для хакеров прочтите, раз троян писать решил

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы форма не отображалась в пенели задач, нужно в конструкторе формы установить свойство `BorderStyle` в `bsDialog` или `bsToolWindow`, например. Для скрытия нужно тоже в конструкторе установить `Visible := false`.
Все это нужно устанавливать в дизайнере или программно присвоить в конструкторе класса формы.
**UPD**
Попробуйте еще

```
ShowWindow(Self.Handle, SW_HIDE);
```

Для того, что бы `visible := false` сработало, нужно похоже сначала `StayOnTop := true;` делать.

Answer (score 3):

```
Form1.Hide;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin

ShowWindow(Application.Handle, SW_HIDE);

end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну, если просто надо, чтобы его не было видно, можно в OnCreate установить его свойство visible на false.

Comment: Пробовал, не получается.

Comment: Что не получается? Скрывается, но не сразу? Обновил ответ.

Comment: Вообще не скрывается, как будто ничего ни делал.

Answer (score 1):

В FormCreate введите

Action:=caNone;
Application.Minimize;

Comment: Думаю просто и ясно.